# NOT IN in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a problem with an XPath expression.

Here is my XML document :

```
<xml>
  <old><index>A</index><type>red</type></old>
  <old><index>A</index><type>blue</type></old>
  <old><index>B</index><type>red</type></old>
  <old><index>C</index><type>red</type></old>
  <new><index>B</index><type>blue</type></new>
</xml>
```

I want to display `<new>` only if (new/index AND new/type) != (old/index AND old/type) for each old.

For exemple,

```
/xml/new[not(index = /xml/old/index) and not(type != /xml/old/type)]
```

is bad because B exists and blue exists.

Thank you.

Bob.

Comment: So you have multiple `old` nodes and only one `new` node? or there are several `new` nodes in actual xml?

Comment: Yes, only one `new` node, multiple `old` nodes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below XPath

```
/xml[not(old[index = /xml/new/index and type = /xml/new/type])]/new
```

This should return `new` node only in case `xml` *doesn't contain `old` node with `index` AND `type` same as in `new`*